# Sending strings"" on visual studio with others elements C#

Tags: c#

Hi I'm a beginner in **C#**, I want to create a program that will send code to an arduino card.
   My problem is :
**serialport1.write = "1c" & ScrollBar1.Value.ToString() & "w";**
                                                                                               Visual studio say to me "&" can't be use with that string
I don't know how to send this code ... out it has to be **1c0-255w**
Thx for help, I'm sure there is a way to replace "&" by anything else.

Comment: Use +. & is a logical operator in c#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code is in vb.net, the syntax in c# is with "+" instead of "&".